# Does Pharaoh's daughter speak Hebrew in Exodus 2:10 or is the book of Exodus simply translating what she said in Egyptian into Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, moshe-rabbeinu

Exodus 2:10 says: "And the child grew, and she brought him unto Pharaoh’s daughter, and he became her son. And she called his name Moses, and said: ‘Because I drew him out of the water.’" Is the text implying that Pharaoh's daughter spoke Hebrew or did she use the Egyptian equivalent of one drawn out and the text is just translating what she said in Egyptian into Hebrew for a Hebrew audience?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89130/moses-hebrew-name-was-given-to-him-in-egyptian https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79307/what-egyptian-greek-text-was-ibn-ezra-consulting-for-his-commentary-on-the-name

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98033/why-did-moshe-keep-his-name-if-it-was-given-by-an-egyptian/98034#98034

Comment: Is https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89130/moses-hebrew-name-was-given-to-him-in-egyptian your question?

Comment: @msh looks like a dupe to me

Comment: Many [pharaonic names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pharaohs) contain the [ancient Egyptian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_language) particle **mose**, [meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses#Name) **born**, which Biblical Judaism then proceeded to [reinterpret](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/2564) in a manner befitting [classical Hebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_Hebrew).